# How do I implement this jQuery into an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to implement this snippet someone gave me from another post that works perfectly, but I do not know the proper way to insert it.

I am working on Wordpress via the Elementor block builder and have a custom HTML widget I am trying to inset this code into.

I'm a novice who is just getting into the usage of JavaScript and jQuery. Running it on StackOverflow works perfect because I can put the HTML in the HTML section and the jQuery in the JavaScript section, but obviously I cannot on Wordpress.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#image1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12D.gif");
    var url = $(this).attr("data-click-href");
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = url;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12.gif" data-click-href="https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/" id="image1">
```

Comment: Have you try this? https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-html/

Comment: Do you get any console errors when you try to run it on WordPress as a custom HTML Widget?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is already enqueue in Wordpress. You do not need to include <script src=''...jquery'/>

You can use HTML block from Elementor and add your HTML code. Javascript Code needs to be enclosed in script tag.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#image1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12D.gif");
    var url = $(this).attr("data-click-href");
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = url;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<img src="https://lowlifeclothing.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Loop12.gif" data-click-href="https://lowlifeclothing.co/shop/" id="image1">
```

Now when you click on the image, the deer will play dead!

Look at this image for reference code sample -

https://askteammate.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/StackOverFlow-Question-64960881.png

Comment: FYI - I can't reliably use `$(...)`—if I change it to `jQuery(...)` it works better. However, this doesn't work with Elementor HTML widgets. For me jQuery works when in the editor, but not on the front end. Elementor Pro support has been a bit lacking on this (still trying to get them to actually review this).